# Generic Extension Methods C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, generics, collections

I'm creating a few extension methods that i want to use on different collections mostly those that implement `IList` and array collections `[]` whenever im creating an extension method i need to create 2 instead of just 1 so that it can work for both

```
    public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> inputCollection)
    {

    }

    public static T[] Shuffle<T>(this T[] inputCollection)
    {

    }
```

Most of my methods require work with the indexes so i cant use `IEnumerable` is there some other way that i can write just 1 extension method and use it for both of the desired collections ? Also sometimes i use the `string` which is one more method.

Comment: If you are going to return a new collection then IEnumerable<> is plenty good enough.  But surely you don't actually want to do that so ICollection<> is the right flavor.

Comment: Arrays implement `IList<T>`, so you might not need one of them (depending on the implementation).

Comment: Option 1 is to use nongeneric `IList` interface implemented by both arrays and `List<T>` the other option is to create wrapper for array that implements IList<T> but reads and writes from underlaying array, in in array ext method you can `new Wrapper(array).ListExtMethod()`

Comment: @csharpfolk You don't need a wrapper. `T[]` already implements `IList<T>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value)
```

signature; and use it

```
IList<T> list = Shuffle(myList).ToList();
T[] array = Shuffle(myArray).ToArray();
```

or even

```
IList<T> list = myList.Shuffle().ToList();
T[] array = myArray.Shuffle().ToArray();
```

Comment: But if i use `this IEnumerable<T> value` i cant apply indexing in my method.

Comment: @PreqlSusSpermaOhranitel: just translate it to, say, array: `T[] data =  value.ToArray();`

Comment: Great that fixes my problem !

Comment: This is the appropriate solution, since LINQ methods don't mutate the original `IEnumerable<T>` instance. However if you wanted to operate on original instances (in which case I wouldn't use an extension method), you could use `IList<T>` as the parameter since both `List<T>` and `T[]` already implement `IList<T>` (which is indexable), and you wouldn't have to create the copy inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this extension method, because all `List` objects are inherited from `IEnumerable`.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MethodName<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value)
```